# getAdapterPosition Deprecated What should I use instead?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Android studio gives me  a waning `getAdapterPosition` is deprecated :

```
public class UserStatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserStatusAdapter.UserStatusHolder> {  

 public class UserStatusHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.user_status_image)
        CircleImageView user_status_image;
        @BindView(R.id.add_user_status)
        AppCompatButton add_user_status;
        @BindView(R.id.user_status_name)
        AppCompatTextView user_status_name;
        public UserStatusHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUserStoryAdapterListener != null)
                    mUserStoryAdapterListener.getUserStories(dataList, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
........ }
```

what should I use instead to get the adapter position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition())

Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder with respect to the [**RecyclerView.Adapter**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter).

```
mUserStoryAdapterListener.getUserStories(dataList, getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: what is the difference between them?

Comment: getAdapterPosition ()- This method is confusing when adapters nest other adapters.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya please answer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271696/recyclerview-not-updating-after-calling-changecursor

Answer (score 1):

This method is confusing when adapters nest other adapters. If you are calling this in the context of an Adapter, you probably want to call `getBindingAdapterPosition()` or if you want the position as `RecyclerView` sees it, you should call `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`.

References : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()