# RecyclerView not updating after calling changeCursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

**Background:**

I have an orders table in my database whose data I show in `RecyclerView`. I do it by using a `CursorAdapter` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`. All of this is done in parent activity.

Besides this I have a child activity which is responsible for adding new orders to orders table and then coming back to parent activity to show all the orders in `RecyclerView` including the newly ones just created. New orders are added by starting a child activity in `addOrder()`.

**Problem:**

When I come back from child activity to parent activity (after successful adding new orders to orders table) I try to refresh the `RecyclerView` with the help of `changeCursor()` but I don't see the `RecyclerView` getting updated with new data.

**My Code:**

***Adapter:***

```
public class OrderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private CursorAdapter userList;
    private Context context;

    public OrderListAdapter(Context context, Cursor list){

        this.context = context;
        userList = new CursorAdapter(this.context, list, 0) {
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                // Code for inflater
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                // Code for bindView
            }
        };
    }

    public CursorAdapter getCursorAdapter(){ return userList; }

    public double getTotalPrice(){
        Cursor records = userList.getCursor();
        double total = 0;
        while (records.moveToNext()) {
              double price = records.getDouble(4);
              int quantity = records.getInt(3);
              total += price * quantity;
        }
        return total;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = userList.newView(context, userList.getCursor(), parent);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        userList.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        userList.bindView(holder.itemView, context, userList.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return userList.getCount(); }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // declaring holder variables
        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
           // Initialising holder variables
        }
    }
}
```

***ParentActivity:***

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private TextView totalText;
     private OrderListAdapter orderAdapter;
     private RecyclerView orderView; 

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);
         totalText = findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
         showTable();
     }

     private void setAdapter(Cursor records){
         orderView = findViewById(R.id.tableContent); 
         orderView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
         orderList = new ArrayList<>();
         orderAdapter = new OrderListAdapter(this, records);
         orderView.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
     }

     private void showTotalPrice(){
         double totalPrice = orderAdapter.getTotalPrice();
         totalText.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
     }

     private void showTable(String item){
         totalText.setText("0.0");
         Cursor records = db.query("orders", null, null, null, null, null, null);
         setAdapter(records);
         showTotalPrice();        
     }

     private void updateTable(){
         Cursor records = db.query("orders", null, null, null, null, null, null);
         orderAdapter.getCursorAdapter().changeCursor(records);
     }
     // This is called on click of a button 
     public void addOrder(View view){
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChildActivity.class));
         updateTable(); // this doesn't update the RecyclerView
         showTotalPrice();
     }
}
```

If I comment out `showTotalPrice()` in `addOrder()` the `RecyclerView` seems to get updated with new orders. Why is that the case ? why is `showTotalPrice()` preventing the update ? I need `showTotalPrice()` in order to show the updated total price of the products in the table.

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: We don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` its called by `changeCursor()` internally look at the comments of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026719/how-to-update-listview-in-case-of-cursoradapter-usage:

Comment: As I said in my post the `RecyclerView` gets updated only if I comment out `showTotalPrice()` so the problem is with `showTotalPrice()`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks :) please help I still can't find a solution :(

Comment: Kindly create a demo

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I found a better approach Thanks anyways :) https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59